# Middleware whitelisting with a wildcard

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have a global middleware on my app that works, but now I want to whitelist some URL's from this middleware.

The URLS I want to whitelist look like this `api/invitation/RANDOMSTRING`. So I was thinking of using a wildcard.

I wrote this function, with the first part being my whitelist logic.

**MIDDLEWARE**:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (['/api/invitation', '/api/invitation/*'].indexOf(req.url) !== -1) {
    return next();
  } else {

     DO STUFF...

  }
});
```

However the problem I have is that my whitelist logic

**Whitelist:**

```
if (['/api/invitation', '/api/invitation/*'].indexOf(req.url) !== -1) {
    return next();
```

always returns false, and as a result my whitelist doesn't work. I assume it has something to do with the wildcard, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `indexOf` to match `/api/invitation/*`, it will return true if your `req.url` match exact `/api/invitation/*`, for example:

```
['/api/invitation/*'].indexOf('/api/invitation/*') > -1; // true
['/api/invitation/*'].indexOf('/api/invitation/something') > -1; // false
```

You can use regex for this as below:

```
if (/api\/invitation\/.*/.test(req.url)) {
  next();
}
```

For tests:

```
/api\/invitation\/.*/.test('api/invitation/hehe'); // true
/api\/invitation\/.*/.test('api/invitation/1'); // true
/api\/invitation\/.*/.test('api/customer/hehe'); // false
```

Ref:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Hope it helps